# PyAutoGui isn't pressing "enter"

Tags: python, roblox

I'm trying to get python to automate sending a message in Roblox and it's typing out the message, but it's not sending it by pressing "enter", it's only pressing "space".

I watched a ton of videos on how to get it to press enter and I also tried different keys to see which one would be enter but nothing worked. I'm trying to get it so send a randomized message from a list every 1 - 2 minutes. Here's my code:

```
import pyautogui
import time

time.sleep(5)
pyautogui.write("/Test", interval = 0.1)
pyautogui.press('enter')
```

Comment: "I watched a ton of videos on how to get it to press space and I also tried different keys to see which one would be space"  if what you want to send is **enter** why are you looking videos on how to send **space** and trying keys to see which one is **space**? shouldn't you try keys to see which one is **enter**? or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your IDE, than if it works try it inside Roblox.

```
import pyautogui
import time
import random

messages = ["Hello!", "How are you?", "Nice to meet you!"]
time.sleep(5)

while True:
    message = random.choice(messages)
    pyautogui.typewrite(message, interval=0.1)
    pyautogui.press('enter')
    time.sleep(random.uniform(60, 120))
```

Comment: So it works in the IDE but it doesn't work in Roblox, I think it's just a problem with Roblox, not the script.

Comment: I dont know how Roblox chat system works but if, for example, you open chat with Enter key, how about adding one more pyautogui.press('enter') right after while True statement to open up chat?
Something like press enter to open chat, type message, hit enter to send?

Comment: It's ok, I think i can still get it to work

Comment: I got it to work, I was just using the wrong launcher lol